# $_POST returning empty values

Tags: php, database, forms

I have created a form, as shown below that displays according to a switch statement. I am needing the inputs from the form submission to either be saved to a table in the WordPress Database or to be saved to a text file saved in the uploads section of the sites core files. However, when the form is submitted it is outputting empty values for the variables. What am I doing wrong? How can this be fixed? Thank you!

Code for the form's switch statement:

```
<?php /* code for pop-up button conditions */
$host = 'https://' .$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; /* gets the current page's URL */
switch ( $host ){
  case 'https://example1.com/': 
  case 'https://example2.com/': 
  case 'https://example3.com/':
    require 'pop-up-button.php'; /*calls the PHP file containing the code for the form*/
    echo '<button id="close" class="open-button" onclick="openForm()"></button>'; /*echo runs and outputs the HTML code for the button */
    break; 
  default : 
    break; 
}; ?>
```

Code for the form:

```
<html>
<style>

/* Stylings for Heading Statement */
    .h3{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 24px;
        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
    }
/* Stylings for checkbox */
    .box{
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
        color: white;
    }
/* Stylings for input labels (names and checkbox labels) */
    .input-label{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
    }
/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
    .open-button {
        width: 170px; 
        height: 60px; 
        background-color: transparent; 
        outline: none; 
        position: relative; 
        left: -168px; 
        top: 20px;
    }
/* The popup form - hidden by default */
    .form-popup {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        border: none;
        z-index: 9;
        background-color: #1e1e1e;
      width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }
/* Sets style and size of input fields  */
    .form-popup input[type=text] {
        width: 20%;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
        border: none;
        background: #FFFFFF;
    }
/* Sets color and style of the input boxes when selected */
    .form-popup input:focus {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        outline: none;
    }
/* Stylings of the submit button */
    .btn {
        background-color: #DB2600;
        border-radius: 9999px;
        font-size: 24px;
        width: 120px;
        height: 45px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        color: white;
    }
/* Changes the color of the sugmit button when curser hovers over it */
    .btn:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
/* Hides the default checkbox */
    .box input {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
/* creates custom checkbox */
    .checkmark {
        position: absolute;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
/* Sets the color of checkbox when checked */
    .box input:checked ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: #DB2600;
    }
/* creates checkmark inside checkbox */
    .checkmark:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }
/* Displays checkmark when checkbox is clicked */
    .box input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
        display: block;
    }
/* Positions and styles checkmark */
    .box .checkmark:after {
        left: 7px;
        top: 3px;
        width: 6px;
        height: 12px;
        border: solid white;
        border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
/* Column formatting for checkbox and statement. This is what is aligning the two items. */
    .column1 {
        float: left;
        width: 17%;
    }
    .column2 {
        float: left;
        width: 74%;
        margin-top:-5px;
    }
/* Clears floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

</style>
<body>

<!-- Code for the form -->

    <div class="form-popup" id="Form"> 
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        
        <!-- acknolwdgement statment -->
              <h3 class="h3">Form Statement</h3> 

        <!-- label and input for First Name -->
              <label for="fname" class="input-label">First name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required/> 

        <!-- label and input for Last Name -->
              <label for="lname" class="input-label">&nbsp &nbsp Last name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required/> <br> <br>

        <!-- checkbox and label, placed to columns to achieve desired formating -->
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="column1" style="text-align: right;">
                      <label  class="box" style="border-color: red;">  
                      <input type="checkbox" name="consent" value="agreed" class="box" id="consent" required/>
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                      </label></div>
                  <div class="column2" style="text-align: left;">
                      <label class="input-label"> I have read and understand the above statement.
                      </label>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <br><br>  
        <!-- Submit Button -->
              <input type="submit" onclick = "submitForm()" class="btn">
            

        </form>
    </div>

<script>
    function openForm() { /* Opens Consent Form */
        document.getElementById("Form").style.display = "block";
    }
    function submitForm() {
        document.write = "<?php form_process() ?>"; 
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP that processes the form: (contains statements for both Database insertions and writing to the text file, I truly only need one to work)

```
<?php /* PHP code that processes form */

    function form_process(){
       
        $FirstName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fname", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $LastName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lname", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $Consent = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "consent", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        global $wpdb;
        $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "usernme", "password", "database");
        $table_name = $wpdb -> database . 'table';
        $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('FirstName' => "$FirstName", 'LastName' => "$LastName", 'Consent' => "$Consent"));

        $Date = date("l, F jS, Y");
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
        $Time = date("h:i:sa");

        $data = 'I, ' . $FirstName . ' ' . $LastName . ', ' . $Consent . ' to Form on ' . $Date . ' at ' . $Time . '.' . "\n"; 
        $txtfile = "uploads/Form.txt";
        $fp = fopen($txtfile, 'a+');
        fwrite($fp, $data);
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

Database output:

[image: Database]

Text file output:

[image: Text File]

Comment: In `form_process()` you're accessing `$FirstName` in `wpdb::insert()` before it is defined (after `wpdb::insert()`). It may be beneficial to [Enable Debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) which should point some of these issues out during your testing.

Comment: Ok thank you! I have fixed that and will enable debugging

Comment: The form in the previous version of the question was using the GET method. Did anything change when you switched it to POST?

Comment: No, I've even tried REQUEST

Comment: Also, I've turned debugging on, and I'm not sure if it's related , but the form won't appear when the Database connection and insertion lines are present. It will appear, though, when I'm only sending it to the text file

Comment: @CodingStudent "$wpdb -> database" - did you mean to use `$wpdb->prefix` ? But even if there was an error *in your function*, the `$_POST` array wouldn't be empty unless if your form data was empty. So try dumping that array at the top in your function - `var_dump( $_POST );` - is it really empty, even **after** submitting the form? 

Comment: the "database" is the name of the WordPress database, I changed it to keep it general. Also the var_dump($_POST) outputs array(O){}

Comment: Also, it seems the function is running without it being called. It is outputting the array(O){} upon the page loading and won't allow the form to be pulled up/